# why does sqlalchemy return tuples rather than just the result?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am new to sqlalchemy, and not getting output as expected:

```
q = db.session.query(Country.countrycode).distinct().all()
print(q)
```

returns

```
[('DE',), ('ES',), ('FR',)]
```

The class Country is defined elsewhere, and the column countrycode definitely does not contain a tuple, it's just the two digit codes.

Have checked the type of the 'tuples' and got `<class'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'>`

**Why** does sqlalchemy return its results in this unusual form rather than just the result and nothing else?

Comment: If you want a list of codes, you can do: `q_list = map(lambda x: x[0], q)`